# Drag and drop of media doesn't drop to current spot in timeline

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, timeline

Using Blender 3.2.0

I recently re-installed blender on a fresh install of windows and now when I drag and drop media, it goes to track 1, 0th keyframe when it used to go to the current time and a track where it would fit.

Why did this change and how do I fix it? I want them to drop right where my time is. I tried resetting my settings, but nothing changed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: But when I add going through the Add dropdown and select image / video, it will go to the right spot.